# Deleting columns in array with zeros

Tags: matlab, octave

I have an array that starts of with zeros and continues into other numbers
I would like to delete the columns in the array that start off with zero but keep the other numbers

example of an column array below:

x= [0 0 0 0 0 2 4 6 8 0 1 2];

Answer of column array would look like

x= 2 4 6 8 0 1 2

I'm using octave 3.4.2/matlab

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
x = x(find(x~=0, 1):end);
```

or

```
x(1:find(x~=0,1)-1) = [];
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response but when I try 
x2=x(1:find(x~=0,1)-1) = [];
it comes back as a 0x0 array

Comment: The second bit of code is intended to change x itself, and doing x2 = ... = [] sets x2 to []. Try the first bit of code

Comment: No, you cannot have 2 assignments. Do exactly as I show in the answer. If you need to make a new vector, use the first way: `x2 = x(find(x~=0, 1):end);`

Answer (score 1):

The find command should work for this.

Assuming your vector is x:

```
 find(x ~= 0)
```

Will return all indices where x is non-zero. Just grab the first index and go from there to delete all values from 1 to index.

Answer (score 1):

Logical indexing will work just fine in this case: i.e.,

```
y = x(:,x(1,:)~=0)
```

will do the job for you. The inner logical comparison, `x(1,:)~=0` returns true for every column whose first element is not zero. The indexing operation, `x(:,...)` selects only those columns for which the logical comparison returned true.